# How to pull everything from a specific commit?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

[image]

I'm trying to pull everything from a specific commit im working with other people who have merged there branches that's why I want to pull from this commit how can I do that without messing up my own code? the specific commit is "merge 1" and is the highlighted one

Comment: It's a bit unclear, can you elaborate on what you mean by "pull from this commit"? Pulling implies merging and most workflows merge branches rather than commits. Do you want to "copy" that commit elsewhere? ...or maybe make some other branch have the same code that commit has? Too many possibilities to answer without clarifications, if I may. Also... "without messing up my own code"?! What *should* it do then?

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second command, typically `git merge`*. So maybe you mean *run `git merge` on a specific commit*, but that's not at all clear, as @RomainValeri notes.

Comment: and yet again I remember a bit too late that you can config your pulls to rebase rather than merge... but yes important point. In any case, further details are welcome, OP :-)

Comment: are you looking for [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)? `git checkout` will move your current file state (head) into the desired commit. since you are using sourcetree, you can easily right click the commit you want and click checkout. do remember to commit/stash your changes first though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a branch from any commit. So, knowing sha1 for your commit you can just

```
git branch mybranch a0fbc78
```

Now you have a named branch which points to your commit. from now on you can do many things. You can check it out

```
git checkout mybranch
```

you can create a worktree

```
git worktree add wtree-path mybranch
```

you can clone

```
git clone --single-branch --branch mybranch
```

you can pull it into another repo

```
git pull origin mybranch
```

These all things will not messup with your top of the tree code, assuming that you committed it before all those operations.

Comment: Not sure if the asker is looking for command line options. It's tagged as atlassian-sourcetree

Answer (score 0):

Try `git fetch` instead of `git pull` so that you can get the information from the remote without messing up with your current work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, unfortunately, the only way is creating a new branch from the commit you want to pull and make the changes to the new branch.